# O que é Context e Generated Keys?

Tags: java, jdbc, conexão

Gostaria de saber o que é exatamente o `context` da classe `connection` (já vi métodos em relação a isso como `getConnectionFromContext`, ou algo assim) e Generated Keys como a constante do PreparedStatment: `PreparedStatment.RETURN_GERENERATE_KEYS`

Comment: `getConnectionFromContext`? Onde viu isto? Consegue incluí-lo para ver que contexto é este? Um contexto da JNDI? Inclua mais detalhes sobre este contexto para conseguir ajudá-lo, a outra parte é tranquila ;)

Answer (score 2):

Como você não incluiu mais detalhes sobre o que é este contexto não vou assumir que seja um contexto da `JNDI`, um contexto Spring, CDI, tampouco outro qualquer. Então fou incluir apenas resposta à segunda pergunta :)

- O que é exatamente *Generated Keys*, como a constante [`PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)?

*Generated Keys* são atributos gerados automaticamentes pelo SGBD, como *row id*, *identities*, valores gerados por gatilhos, etc. No JDBC, a partir da versão 3, você pode informar explicitamente ao *statement* se quer ou não que tais valores sejam retornados num `ResultSet`.

A constante [`PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) é usada para indicar que valores auto gerados pelo SGBD devem ser retornados depois da execução do *statement*. Digamos que você tenha a seguinte tabela (usando PostgreSQL como exemplo):

```sql
CREATE TABLE pessoas
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(300),
  CONSTRAINT pessoa_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Dizemos que o `id` será do tipo `serial`, que irá gerar uma `sequence` e será auto gerado pelo PostgreSQL. Para simular a recuperação desse valor podemos fazer algo assim:

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO pessoas(nome) VALUES (?);";
final Connection conn = this.getConnection(); // recupera a conexão de alguma forma
try (final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    ps.setString(1, "Bruno");
    ps.execute();
    try (final ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            final int id = rs.getInt("id"); // pode ser recuperado pela ordem também: rs.getInt(1)
            // faz o que for preciso com os auto gerados
        }
    }
}
```

Ou seja, falamos ao nosso *statement* para popular um `ResultSet` (recuperando por `ps.getGeneratedKeys()`) com todas colunas/chaves que são auto geradas pelo banco de dados, no nosso caso o `serial` *id*.

Esta *feature* pode não ser suportada por todos os *drivers* JDBC, então uma [`SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html) pode ser lançada.

Há também o contrário, quando você quer não quer que de forma alguma tais valores auto gerados sejam retornados, então você pode usar [`PreparedStatement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#NO_GENERATED_KEYS) e o comportamento padrão depende do driver do SGBD.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno ^-^

Comment: @RaphaelAndrade se é apenas isto que precisa, considere [aceitar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) a resposta como a correta :)